# Adding ROI outlines and labels to a grayscale stack and creating montage

Tags: imagej

I have a grayscale image stack with ~100 slices. In selected slices, I have indicated ROIs using the freehand tool and added a label for measurement.

What I would like to do is to generate a montage that contains the selected slices with ROIs and labels indicated as an overlay. I tried to make a substack, add the overlays from the ROI manager and then generate a montage but the montage doesn't show the overlays. I also tried the 'Flatten' command but it requires an RGB image. If I convert the grayscale image to RGB, it overlaps all the ROIs on top of the first image rather than placing them on the right slice.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following macro code creates a montage of flattened views of every ROI in the ROI manager:

```js
myTitle = getTitle();
for (i=0; i<roiManager("count"); i++) {
    selectWindow(myTitle);
    roiManager("select", i);
    run("Select None");
    run("Duplicate...", "title=single-slice");
    run("Restore Selection");
    run("Flatten");
    rename("ready-for-stack");
}
run("Images to Stack", "name=Stack title=ready-for-stack use");
selectWindow("Stack");
run("Make Montage...", "scale=1 increment=1 border=1");
```

To try it, paste the code into the [script editor](http://fiji.sc/Using_the_Script_Editor) (part of [Fiji/ImageJ2](http://imagej.net/Fiji)), choose *Language > IJ1 Macro* and press *Run*.